# React Native: No thing show on the screen after getting data from firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```js
const [tourists, setTourists] = useState(null)
  const [saved,setsave]=useState('');
  const {user, logout} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const getUser = async() => {
    
    await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc( user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      if( documentSnapshot.exists ) {
        
        console.log('User Data in BookMark', documentSnapshot.data());
        const list=[]; 
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        
        console.log('savedPosts: ',documentSnapshot.data().savedPosts);
        documentSnapshot.data().savedPosts.map((object, index) => (
        
         firestore().collection('posts').doc(object).get().then((querySnapshot) => {list.push(querySnapshot.data())})
        ))
        setTourists(list);
        if (loading) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
        
      }
    })
    
    
  }
 
    
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);
  return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
     
     {!loading ? ((tourists ||[]).map((object, index) => (...
```

I have checked through the console and see that firestore worked correctly, I got the data, tourists is not null, but the screen still shows nothing. Can anybody hekp me plz !!!

Comment: Need to see the mapping code, no way of knowing from what you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this part:

```js
const list=[]; 
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
        
        console.log('savedPosts: ',documentSnapshot.data().savedPosts);
        documentSnapshot.data().savedPosts.map((object, index) => (
        
         firestore().collection('posts').doc(object).get().then((querySnapshot) => {list.push(querySnapshot.data())})
        ))
        setTourists(list);
```

Becase you use `then` the `setTourists(list)` will always save an empty array because `then` finished after you already set the value. Also a `map` doesn't support async calls. We need to use a `for` loop for this.

Change your code to something like this:

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  await firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(async (documentSnapshot) => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        console.log("User Data in BookMark", documentSnapshot.data());
        const list = [];
        const posts = [];
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());

        documentSnapshot.data().savedPosts.map((object, index) => {
          posts.push(object);
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
          const post = posts[i];
          const docSnapshot = await firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(post)
            .get();

          list.push(docSnapshot.data());
        }

        setTourists(list);
        if (loading) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it still not working, the querySnapshot is null!

Comment: What value does `object` have?

Comment: the document id, btw it should be post, not object

Comment: Can you pls log the `post` and `docSnapshot` from the update answer.  Also the `list` and write in the commend what data you see.

Comment: It works correctly. Thank you very muchhhhhh !! So why docSnapshot solve the problem ?

Comment: Probably a typo in my first answer  docSnapshot is just a variable name.